# Using FOR JSON PATH, can I make INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES optional?

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored proc to return JSON formatted results. I want to add an input parameter to optionally enable INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES using a CASE expression but I cannot get it to work. @includeNullValues is the input parameter defaulting to 0. Can anyone help here?

```
SELECT.....

FROM         #matterdetail md
ORDER BY CASE  
    WHEN @includeNullValues = 1 THEN
            md.FileNumber
            FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES  
    ELSE
        md.FileNumber
        FOR JSON PATH
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the syntax of the clause in the MSDN. In this [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql) we have:

[image]

You can see how to `read` the syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql). So, you are not allowed to use neither variables or expressions.

You have the following options:

- control the flow using `IF ELSE`
- build dynamic T-SQL statement and execute it

Comment: Thanks, wound up using IF/ELSE around the entirety of the final select statement in the proc, I couldn't find a way to modify only the order by clause. Not pretty but it works.